# How to change the clef of a container in mingus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lilypond

In mingus, the following code creates a single staff with a treble cleff and a C2 note.

```
from mingus.containers.bar import Bar
from mingus.containers.track import Track
from mingus.extra.lilypond import *
b = Bar("C")
t = Track(b)
t.add_notes("C-2")
sheet = from_Track(t)
to_png(sheet, "example1")
```

Alternatively, the following code creates two staves, each with a treble clef and a C5 and C2. respectively.

```
from mingus.containers.bar import Bar
from mingus.containers.track import Track
from mingus.containers.composition import Composition
from mingus.extra.lilypond import *
b1 = Bar("C")
b2 = Bar("C")
t1 = Track(b1)
t2 = Track(b2)
t1.add_notes("C-5")
t2.add_notes("C-2")
c = Composition()
c.add_track(t1)
c.add_track(t2)
sheet = from_Composition(c)
to_png(sheet, "example2")
```

How do I force mingus/lilypond to use a bass clef in either of these examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the source, it doesn't look like it's supported!

I was able to code up a work-around.  It relies on using the Instrument class, where the `clef` property is supposed to be defined.  Note that when you are defining your `Track()` objects, you should *not* be passing in `Bar()` objects, only `Instrument()` objects.

My approach overrides the default `from_Track()` function in lilypond.  It calls the original version of `from_Track()` and then makes sure to add whatever clef notation you want from here: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/clef-styles .  It's a simple patch, so there's no error-checking if you pick a bad clef style, so just make sure it's valid or else it'll revert to the default treble.

Here's what I got working:

```python
from mingus.containers.bar import Bar
from mingus.containers.instrument import Instrument
from mingus.containers.track import Track
from mingus.containers.composition import Composition
import mingus.extra.lilypond as lilypond
from_Track_Orig = lilypond.from_Track

def from_Track(track):
    global from_Track_Orig
    result = from_Track_Orig(track)
    if isinstance(result,str) and track.instrument is not None and isinstance(track.instrument.clef,str):
        result = "%s \clef %s %s" % (result[:1], track.instrument.clef.split()[0], result[1:])
    return result
lilypond.from_Track = from_Track

i = Instrument()
i.clef = 'bass'
b1 = Bar("C")
b2 = Bar("C")
t1 = Track()
t1.add_bar(b1)
t2 = Track(i)
t2.add_bar(b2)
t1.add_notes("C-5")
t2.add_notes("C-2")
c = Composition()
c.add_track(t1)
c.add_track(t2)
sheet = lilypond.from_Composition(c)
lilypond.to_png(sheet, "example2")
```

[image: sheet music with treble and bass clefs]

Comment: Note that the clefs are case-sensitive!  So "Bass" and "bass" are not the same.  Just make sure it matches that notation reference.